# Where IN clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How to make a where in clause similar to one in SQL Server?

I made one by myself but can anyone please improve this?

```
    public List<State> Wherein(string listofcountrycodes)
    {
        string[] countrycode = null;
        countrycode = listofcountrycodes.Split(',');
        List<State> statelist = new List<State>();

        for (int i = 0; i < countrycode.Length; i++)
        {
            _states.AddRange(
                 from states in _objdatasources.StateList()
                 where states.CountryCode == countrycode[i].ToString()
                 select new State
                 {
                    StateName  = states.StateName                    

                 });
        }
        return _states;
    }
```

Answer (score 314, accepted):

This expression should do what you want to achieve.

```
dataSource.StateList.Where(s => countryCodes.Contains(s.CountryCode))
```

Comment: this will compare string values, but what about ids??

Comment: @JitendraPancholi if you create a List<int> you can check for ids. It is supported in .Net 4. Not sure of the earlier versions.

Answer (score 111):

This will translate to a where in clause in Linq to SQL...

```
var myInClause = new string[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};

var results = from x in MyTable
              where myInClause.Contains(x.SomeColumn)
              select x;
// OR
var results = MyTable.Where(x => myInClause.Contains(x.SomeColumn));
```

In the case of your query, you could do something like this...

```
var results = from states in _objectdatasource.StateList()
              where listofcountrycodes.Contains(states.CountryCode)
              select new State
              {
                  StateName = states.StateName
              };
// OR
var results = _objectdatasource.StateList()
                  .Where(s => listofcountrycodes.Contains(s.CountryCode))
                  .Select(s => new State { StateName = s.StateName});
```

Comment: Thank you ;) Helped me as well +1

Answer (score 51):

I like it as an extension method:

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
{
    return list.Contains(source);
}
```

Now you call:

```
var states = _objdatasources.StateList().Where(s => s.In(countrycodes));
```

You can pass individual values too:

```
var states = tooManyStates.Where(s => s.In("x", "y", "z"));
```

Feels more natural and closer to sql.

Comment: where should i write this extension method

Comment: @Rohaan, in any static class (that is not generic and not nested)

Comment: There's only mileage in writing the extension class if you're going to be reusing the Where In part of your linq. Upvoted the answer, but just wanted to let others who come across this question and go straight for the extension method route.

Comment: @Jurg It's pretty frequently required, no? I use it all the time. Works fine for Linq to Objects, havent tried for IQueryables.

Comment: No what I meant was, it's used frequently sure however in a particular project if you only need to do this in say a single controller (aka once) then there's an extension method is not required. This was more for people who are new to c#/linq :)

Comment: @nawfal How to make it work of list of list? for example there is a list of Students which has multiple SubjectIds. Now I Want to find out, all students with SubjectIds...let's say 1,2,3

Comment: @Gopu_Tunas use SelectMany to flatten out the collection, in general. Or may be  `students.Where(s => s.SubjectIds.Any(subj => subj.In(1, 2, 3)))`

Comment: Is this method efficient like 'WHERE IN' in SQL? I think the implemented 'In' method should be executed for each member of list, which I think it will cause too much overhead for Linq-2-SQL queries.

Comment: @VSB Extension methods wont even work for Linq-2-SQL. You will have to call Contains directly, which will be executed as `IN`.

Answer (score 18):

```
public List<Requirement> listInquiryLogged()
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext dt = new DataClassesDataContext(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString))
    {
        var inq = new int[] {1683,1684,1685,1686,1687,1688,1688,1689,1690,1691,1692,1693};
        var result = from Q in dt.Requirements
                     where inq.Contains(Q.ID)
                     orderby Q.Description
                     select Q;

        return result.ToList<Requirement>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it's equivalence method syntax?

Comment: Thank you so very much for this, been struggling for days and this was the only thing that worked. So simple and effective a solution.

Answer (score 10):

The "IN" clause is built into linq via the .Contains() method.

For example, to get all People whose .States's are "NY" or "FL":

```
using (DataContext dc = new DataContext("connectionstring"))
{
    List<string> states = new List<string>(){"NY", "FL"};
    List<Person> list = (from p in dc.GetTable<Person>() where states.Contains(p.State) select p).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from state in _objedatasource.StateList()
where listofcountrycodes.Contains(state.CountryCode)
select state
```

Answer (score 2):

This little bit different idea. But it will useful to you. I have used sub query to inside the linq main query.

**Problem:**

Let say we have document table. Schema as follows
schema : *document(name,version,auther,modifieddate)*
composite Keys : name,version

So we need to get latest versions of all documents.

**soloution**

```
 var result = (from t in Context.document
                          where ((from tt in Context.document where t.Name == tt.Name
                                orderby tt.Version descending select new {Vesion=tt.Version}).FirstOrDefault()).Vesion.Contains(t.Version)
                          select t).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<State> GetcountryCodeStates(List<string> countryCodes)
{
    List<State> states = new List<State>();
    states = (from a in _objdatasources.StateList.AsEnumerable()
    where countryCodes.Any(c => c.Contains(a.CountryCode))
    select a).ToList();
    return states;
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.