# The 'in' predicate in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, in-operator

In T-SQL, we have

```
where empid in (1, 3, 5)
```

Now suppose I have a `List<int>`, how do I write a LINQ to Entities query, namely a predicate for `Where()` to get the equivalent of the above SQL query?  Or this is not supported at all?

Thanks,

Comment: this might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959752/where-in-clause-in-linq

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
var Products = from product in dbctx.Products
            where itemQuery.Contains(product.ProductID)
            select product;
```

Comment: Cool, 'Contains' will be translated and is what I want. Thanks.