# linq query with dynamic where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq, c#-4.0

I'm need to do the equivalent of a t-sql statement like this using LINQ:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE idnumber IN('1', '2', '3')
```

so in LINQ I have:

```
Dim _Values as String = "1, 2, 3"
Dim _Query = (From m In mytable Where idnumber = _Values Select m).ToList()
```

Not sure what to do with _Values to make idnumber evaluate each value in the string.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959752/where-in-clause-in-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim _Values as String = "1, 2, 3"
Dim _Query = (From m In mytable Where _Values.Split(", ").Contains(m.idnumber) Select m).ToList()
```

Comment: _Values needs to be an array.

Comment: Right, I missed it. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I will go for `Inner Join` in this context. If I would have used `Contains`, it would `Iterate unnecessarily` 6 times `despite of the fact that there is just one match`.

### C# Version

```
var desiredNames = new[] { "Pankaj", "Garg" }; 

var people = new[]  
{  
    new { FirstName="Pankaj", Surname="Garg" },  
    new { FirstName="Marc", Surname="Gravell" },  
    new { FirstName="Jeff", Surname="Atwood" }  
}; 

var records = (from p in people 
               join filtered in desiredNames on p.FirstName equals filtered  
               select p.FirstName
              ).ToList();
```

---

### VB.Net Version

```
Dim desiredNames = New () {"Pankaj", "Garg"}

Dim people = New () {New With { _
    .FirstName = "Pankaj", _
    .Surname = "Garg" _
}, New With { _
    .FirstName = "Marc", _
    .Surname = "Gravell" _
}, New With { _
    .FirstName = "Jeff", _
    .Surname = "Atwood" _
}}

Dim records = ( _
    Join filtered In desiredNames On p.FirstName = filtered).ToList()
```

### Disadvantages of Contains

Suppose I have two list objects.

```
List 1      List 2
  1           12
  2            7
  3            8
  4           98
  5            9
  6           10
  7            6
```

### Using Contains, it will search for each List-1 item in List-2 that means iteration will happen 49 times !!!

Comment: Are you sure `Join` won't make that all iterations? It has to be done somehow itself.

Comment: In SQL Server I will not like you go with `Cursor`