# How to use Linq to search for set of codes similarly "where in" in SQL

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone help how to use the associated search using linq ("where in" in sql)?

Linq Where search follows here,

```
1. select * from tablename where code = 'code1'
`string[] numbers = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

string searchNumber = "two";
var number = from number1 in numbers
                     where number1 == searchNumber
                     select number1;

foreach (var n in number)
    Console.WriteLine(n);

        Console.ReadLine();`
```

How to search the set of codes using LINQ?

```
2. select * from tablename where code in ('code1','code2')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where IN clause in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959752/where-in-clause-in-linq)

Answer (score 2):

For first answer use this

```
var result = tablename.Where(x => x.code == "code1");
```

For second answer use this

```
List<string> str = new List<string>(){ "code1" , "code2" };

var result = tablename.Where(x => str.Contains(x.code));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of..

```
string[] codes = { "code1", "code2" };
var selections = tablename.Where(x => codes.Contains(x.code));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] searchNumber = {"two","one"};
        var number = from number1 in numbers
                     where searchNumbers.Contains(number1)
                     select number1;

        foreach (var n in number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: If the input is string searchNumber = "'two','three'";

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're going against. If you're using Entity Framework then you're going to need to look up creating an In statement. If you're just using Linq against an IEnumerable, contains will do what you want.

The reason being that if you're executing this against a database, the provider has to have implemented the Contains. Entity Framework doesn't IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invert the way you're thinking about this.
Ask if numbers.Contains(searchNumber). Something like:

```
var result = from n in numbers
                 where numbers.Contains(searchNumber)
                 select n;
```