# Find an item in a generic list by specifying multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Most often we find generic list with code like:

```
CartItem Item = Items.Find(c => c.ProductID == ProductID);
Item.Quantity = Quantity;
Item.Price = Price;
```

So the above code finds and updates with other data, but if I want to find by multiple conditions, then how do I write the code?

I want to write code like:

```
CartItem Item = Items.Find(c => c.ProductID == ProductID and c.ProductName == "ABS001");
```

Please guide me for multiple conditions when we find generic list.

Comment: && instead of and

Comment: If you need you can also use ||  (depends on condition)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this:

```
CartItem Item = Items.Find(c => (c.ProductID == ProductID) && (c.ProductName == "ABS001"));
```

Comment: C# isn't a C++. There's no need in extra brackets.

Comment: Yep, thnx, I know. But I use them to improve readability. It's just a code style wich become a habit.

Comment: How about if you have a an `IN CLAUSE` for the second operation?

Comment: Something like that: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959752/where-in-clause-in-linq )?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
Items.Find(c => c.ProductID == ProductID && c.ProductName == "ABS001");
```

The body of lambda expression is just a method. You can use in it all language constructs, as in regular method.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I prefer

```
Items.Find(item => item.ProductId == ProductID && item.ProductName.Equals("ABS001"));
```

Comment: I tend to reverse the Equals to prevent a problem where item.ProductName is null. I would write `Items.Find(item => item.ProductId == ProductID && "ABS001".Equals(item.ProductName));` because you know "ABS001" is not null before run time.

Answer (score 3):

Use *&&* instead of *and*

```
var result = Items.Find(item => item.ProductId == ProductID && item.ProductName == "ABS001");
```

Answer (score 0):

It annoys me when someone named a variable with the first char in uppercase, so (productID instead of ProductID):

```
CartItem Item = Items.Find(c => (c.ProductID == productID) && (c.ProductName == "ABS001"));
```

:)