# Find object that meets multiple conditions using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to find an object in my database that meets two conditions, I did a search on stackoverflow and found this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406750/find-an-item-in-a-generic-list-by-specifying-multiple-conditions) which looks exactly like what I need.  However, I have this code:

```
if (db.MinimumProductInfo.Find(pc => pc.ItemCode == productInfoWithNote.ItemCode && pc.Region == productInfoWithNote.Region))
```

and I am receiving this error:

> Cannot Convert Lambda Expression to type 'object[]' because it is not
>   a delegate type.

MinimumProductInfo is my class and productInfoWithNote is the viewmodel that I pass in to the method.

Comment: `Find` is for locating by primary key.  I think you want to use `Where`

Comment: @stephen.vakil Find() actually only works on List<T> while Where() works on an IEnumerable<T>, but yes I agree it should be changed

Comment: @RH6 I assumed it was an attempt to use [`DbSet.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx) (which seems to match the error)

Comment: @stephen.vakil dbSet.Find() is a different method than the Linq Find() method

Comment: @RH6 The code is invoking the former, which expects `object[]` as the parameter, not a predicate.  Thus the error.

Comment: Where is `Find()` coming from? I see nothing in `System.Linq`.

Comment: LINQ doesn't have a `Find` method. This is about instance methods of `List<T>` and `DbSet<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using   `FirstOrDefault` which will return `null` if no object meets the conditions:

```
 var myObject = db.MinimumProductInfo.FirstOrDefault(pc => pc.ItemCode == 
        productInfoWithNote.ItemCode && pc.Region == productInfoWithNote.Region);

    if(myObject != null)
    {
         // use your object here
    }
```

**NOTE**:  `Find` method returns the first match element if exists and if not it will return the default value of element's type and you are using it like it will return a boolean value.

Comment: don't use `object`. Write the actual type or `var`