# How to write a LINQ query to select from a collection with given set of matching IDs

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm using a self tracking entity model. `ProductInstallation` is a DTO which contains all the details about the product installation for a company.

The `UserRoles` entity holds the relationship in-between the Product-System Role-UserID.

As an example:

> Product: Inventory
>
> System Role : PurchasingUser
>
> User ID : hasithaH <- (Suppose me)

using the below LINQ query, I can get the distinct UserIDs.

```
string[] userIDs = productInstallation.UserRoles
                  .Select(u=>u.UserID).Distinct().ToArray();
```

now I need to get all the User Profiles for the UserIDs I queried in above steps.

```
productInstallation.SystemUsers = context.SystemUsers.Select(u=> u.UserID ..???
```

In SQL point of view, this is the query I want:

```
Select * from SystemUsers where UserID in ('UserA','UserB','UserC')
```

How should I write a LINQ query to get this done?

Comment: See this similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959752/where-in-clause-in-linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write it as follows:

```
var result = context.SystemUsers.Where(su => 
               productInstallation.UserRoles.Any(ur => su.UserID == ur.UserId));
```

Or if both sources are not `IQuerable` from the same db:

```
string[] userIDs = productInstallation.UserRoles
                  .Select(u=>u.UserID).Distinct().ToArray();

var result = context.SystemUsers.Where(su => 
                   userIDs.Contains(su.UserID));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
productInstallation.SystemUsers = 
context.SystemUsers.FindAll(u=> userIDs.Contains(u.UserID))
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.Where`?

Comment: Yes where or we can use FindAll

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to do here is join the two tables.  Using a Join you can do this in one query rather than executing two separate queries:

```
var systemUsers = from userRole in UserRoles
                  join systemUser in SystemUsers
                  on userRole.UserID equals systemUser.UserID
                  select systemUser;
```

Comment: Doing a `join` does not give the same result as an `in`

Comment: @Magnus In the general case, no, but they're very similar operations and often will have the same result.  Based on the context it seems that he's logically trying to Join the data, so if that's the relationship between these data sets then either would work, but a Join would be more effective and semantically appropriate.

Comment: If the operation is done in the db the effectiveness of a semi join vs an inner join would be almost identical.