# using linq to match one of each in a list or set

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list thus:

```
List<Option> OptionList = getOptions();
```

an Option has various properties but the important ones are

```
decimal Price 
string EqtCode
```

I then have a second list thus:

```
List<string> EqtCodes
```

What I am trying to do is grab options from OptionList where their EqtCode matches **ALL** the ones in the EqtCodes list.. BUT, to make it more complicated I actually need them to be grabbed in 'sets' of ALL of the items in the EqtCodes list, **picking the LOWEST price of any duplicates but grabbing them in SETs of everything in the EqtCodes list**
so.. to attempt to explain further

say the eqtCodes has the following in it

```
['A','B','C']
```

and the optionList has

```
{['A',99.99],['A',89.99],['B',20.00],['C',35.00'],['C',30.00]}
```

What I need is ONLY

```
['A',89.99],['B',20.00],['C',30.00']
```

**i dont want it to grab all of the A's and B's and C's unless it gets them in lumps of 1 A, 1 B and 1 C**

selected out
currently I have

```
var whatIwant = OptionList.Where(o=>o.EqtCode.In(EqtCodes));
```

sadly this will grab everything, not to mention ignore the price..
likewise, if the optionlist was

```
  {['A',99.99],['A',89.99],['B',20.00],['C',35.00'],['C',30.00],['B',22.00],['F',33.33], ['B',19.99]}
```

it would need to grab

```
{['A',99.99],['A',89.99],['B',20.00],['C',35.00'],['C',30.00],['B',19.99]}
```

so its basically grabbing '**full sets**' of ALL of the items in the EqtCodes list each time

I am sure LINQ could do this, but I cannot :)

as ever any help much appreciated

thanks

Comment: Why isn't ['A', 99.99] in your desired set.  You need to explain that distinction also.

Comment: Btw, as EqtCode is a string you should be using `"` and not `'`

Comment: ignore single or double quotes just for the explanation

Comment: if picking the lowest is one of the criteria, then why ['A',99.99] is in your second result?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959752/where-in-clause-in-linq

Comment: @GianAcuna not directly related, the question is far more than a simple contains operation, is a group by set operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this.

```
var query = from o in options
            where EqtCodes.Contains(o.EqtCode)
            group o by o.EqtCode into g;
            select g.OrderBy(x => x.Price).First();
```

Additionally, because you talk about its got to be all the members in EqtCodes the following code will return an empty set if not enough items match the criteria.

```
var query = from o in options
            where EqtCodes.Contains(o.EqtCode)
            group o by o.EqtCode into g;
            select g.OrderBy(x => x.Price).First();

 var options = query.ToArray();
 options = query.Length == EqtCodes.Length ? options : new options[0];
```

Multi set solution

```
var q = from o in options
   where EqtCodes.Contains(o.EqtCode)
   group o by o.EqtCode into g
   from i in Enumerable.Range(0, options.Count / EqtCodes.Count)
   let a = new {index = i, value = g.OrderBy(x => x.Price).Skip(i).Take(1)}
   where a.value.Any ()
   group a by a.index into b
   where b.Count() == EqtCodes.Count()
   select b.SelectMany(x => x.value).ToArray();
```

Then to a single set

```
var singleSet = q.SelectMany(x => x);
```

or

```
var singleSet = q.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks, that is fine other than it only grabs 1 set when if it could get 2 I would want that..

Comment: thanks Bob, that is perfect but ends up with an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Option>> where I need a IEnumerable<Option>, can I flatten that somehow?

Comment: @nat use `var singleList = q.SelectMany(x=>x);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var eqtCodes = new [] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
var optionList = new [] 
{
    new [] { 'a', '1' },
    new [] { 'a', '2' },
    new [] { 'b', '1' },
    new [] { 'c', '1' },
    new [] { 'd', '1' }
};

var lessOptionList = from o in optionList
                     group o by o[0] into p
                     select new { first = p.First() };

var result = lessOptionList.Where(a => eqtCodes.Contains(a.first[0]));
```