# sql IN clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get results similar to SQL `IN` clause in terms of LINQ with the help of `Contains()`

I'm doing the following:

```
listData.Where(pr => pr.CD.Contains(cd)).Select(pr => pr.dept_cd).Distinct()
```

This works if `cd` is only one value, but not working when `cd` is a comma-separated string.

How can I achieve `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN IN(VALUE1,VALUE2...)` in case of LINQ?

Comment: Do you mean something like `cd.Split(',').Contains(pr.CD)` (although you may want to split into an array on a previous line instead of as part of the Linq expression)?

Comment: Please check below link


[IN clause with LINQ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959752/where-in-clause-in-linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be reverse. Like below :

```
listData.Where(pr => cd.Contains(pr.CD).Select(pr => pr.dept_cd)).Distinct();
```

Not sure of syntax. But this is the approach. Here, cd is the comma separated string or a string array

Answer (score 0):

use it like as follow

```
var selected = from u in users
               where new[] { "IT", "Admin", "HR" }.Contains(u.dept_cd)
               select u;
```

or if you have `List` of `string` then you should use it as

```
List<string> dept= new List<string>(){"HR", "IT"};

var selected = from u in users
               where dept.Contains(u.dept_cd)
               select u;
```