# Creating LINQ with where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this LINQ:

```
    private static object getObjectModels(DbContext context, IQueryable<int> contractsID)
    {
        return (from objectModel in context.Set<ObjectModel>()
                where "column named conId contains contractsID "
                select new ContractHelper
                {
                    Id = contract.Id,
                    ClientId = contract.ClientId,
                });
    }
```

I need to select from table records where column named conID have values of contractsID.

The contractsID is int array.
The conID is int value column.

What have I write in this row:
where "column named conId contains contractsID"
to get all records where column conID  have item that equal to item in contractsID array?

Comment: You need to replicate an `IN` clause: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959752/where-in-clause-in-linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959752/where-in-clause-in-linq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to invert the where clause and use a 'contains', such as:

```
private static object getObjectModels(DbContext context, IQueryable<int> contractsID)
    {
        return (from objectModel in context.Set<ObjectModel>()
                where objectModel.conId.HasValue && contractsID.Contains(objectModel.conId)
                select new ContractHelper
                {
                    Id = contract.Id,
                    ClientId = contract.ClientId,
                });
    }
```

You might need to convert the IQueryable to a list however.

```
var myIds = contractIDs.ToList();
...
where myIds.Contains(objectModel.conId)
...
```

Comment: objectModel.conId column is nullable so I get error when Itry to use your example.Is there any wy to fix it?

Comment: I'll update my answer with a suggestion, I don't have an EF project to hand to test it though!

Answer (score 2):

You can go with an int array to make linq translate to the correct IN SQL syntax

```
  private static object getObjectModels(DbContext context, IQueryable<int> contractsID)
    {
         // Necessary to translate Contains to SQL IN  CLAUSE
        int [] contractIdsArray = contractsID.ToArray() ; 

        return (from objectModel in context.Set<ObjectModel>()
                where contractIdsArray.Contains(objectModel.conId)
                select new ContractHelper
                {
                    Id = contract.Id,
                    ClientId = contract.ClientId,
                });
    }
```