# linq where clause when id is in an array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method which should return list of Users if the `UserId` is in an array. The array of UserIds is passed to the method.

I'm not sure how to write ..where userid in array?

below `in ids[]` is clearly not correct.

```
public List<User> GetUsers(int[] ids)
{
   return Users.Values.Where(u => u.UserID in ids[]).ToList();
}
```

Any ideas how to correct that?

Thanks,

Comment: the annoyances of typing up a reply to see someones already posted the same thing and a few people are already voting it.. so I deleted it

Comment: @BugFinder This is an old problem which has its own name ([Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/175984)).

Comment: Thanks :) I just hate to see 2 answers the same, its pointless.. even if both are right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where IN clause in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959752/where-in-clause-in-linq)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
public List<User> GetUsers(int[] ids)
{
    return Users.Values.Where(u => ids.Contains(u.UserID)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively to Quentins answer, use this:

```
public List<User> GetUsers(int[] ids)
{
    return Users.Values.Where(u => ids.Any(x => x == u.UserID)).ToList();
}
```