# EF: where..in clause with multiple columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

just trying to get hold on EF. when we work with sql then we often write multiple value inside in clause

```
Select * from customer
Where countryCode in ('gb','us','fr')
```

i was searching how to write the same query with EF and LINQ. i found these code.

```
var countries= new[] {
    new {Country=…, City=…, Address=…},
    …
}

approach 1
------------
var result = locations.Where(l => keys.Any(k => 
                    k.Country == l.Country && 
                    k.City == l.City && 
                    k.Address == l.Address));

approach 2
------------
var result = from loc in Location
             where keys.Contains(new {
                 Country=loc.Country, 
                 City=loc.City, 
                 Address=loc.Address
             }
             select loc;
```

tell me how to translate below sql query to EF without using multiple contains keyword

```
Select * from customer
Where countryCode in ('gb','us','fr')
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/03/25/tip-8-how-to-write-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17154139/6188148

Comment: Please don't edit in answers to your question. Instead, post an answer on the duplicate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you can just do this

```
var countryCodes = new List<string> {"gb","us","fr"}

var locations = Location.Where(loc => countryCodes.Contains(loc.Country));
```